# How to nicely center vertical sliding text

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am having trouble figuring out how to nicely center vertically sliding text on my webpage. Here is the example snipet: 
http://turistickemagnetky.sk/slide/

At the moment the & symbol jumps around to accommodate the sliding text before it. 
What I would like to achieve is to lock the & symbol d in the middle of the page and the sliding text should flow and expand around it as necessary. I am pretty sure there is just some minor css change, but I cant figure it out so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See if this can help, i think it's duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css

Comment: And to help you better, can you show us some of the code you tried so far?

Comment: Please insert the relevant code into the question itself

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: flex;` Remove margins from `.cd-intro` and set `width: 100%` (first, unset the max-width). Once `.cd-intro` is set to 100% width and flexed, give it a `height: 100vh;` and `align-items: center; justify-content: center;`

That actually worked for me. I don't know if that's what you're looking for.

```
.cd-intro {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Not the vertical alignment is the problem here

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS:

```
section.cd-intro {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

section.cd-intro > :nth-child(1) {
    justify-self: end;
}

section.cd-intro > :nth-child(2) {
    margin: auto .25em;
}

section.cd-intro > :nth-child(3) {
    justify-self: start;
}
```